# Python ctypes and pointers as function arguments

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I wrote a C library to interface with a hardware device over USB, and have used the library successfully with other C code, so I know it works. I want to call this library from Python, and in order to do so I need to pass a struct by reference so that the library can modify it. The structure is defined:

```
typedef struct eventNode eventNode;
struct eventNode{
    int channels;
    int samples;
    uint16_t** event;
    eventNode* next;
    eventNode* prev;
}
```

and in Python I have defined:

```
class eventNode(Structure):
    pass

eventNode._fields_ = [("channels", c_int),
            ("samples", c_int),
            ("event",POINTER(POINTER(c_uint16))),
            ("prev",POINTER(eventNode)),
            ("next",POINTER(eventNode))]
```

which I believe is correct. Essentially I used this to implement a linked list, which my library can modify by calling a method with signature `void getFromCAEN(int, char*, eventNode**, eventNode**)`. The last two arguments are pointers to pointers to the list head and tail, respectively. My python code creates these pointers by calling:

```
queueHead = POINTER(eventNode)()
queueTail = POINTER(eventNODE)()
```

which should initially be NULL (None in ctypes) so that the library knows the list is empty. When I call this function with the line

```
caenlib.getFromCAEN(handle,buff,byref(queueHead),byref(queueTail))
```

a linked list should be formed by the library, which I then attempt to index through with the following block:

```
cur = queueHead
while cur:
    i+=1
    print("event!",i)
    print(addressof(cur))
    print(cur.contents.channels,cur.contents.samples)
    print(cur.contents.event)
    print(cur.contents.next) #print next object in line
    cur = cur.contents.next
    print(cur)               #this prints a different address for some reason
```

And the output of all those print statements is this:

```
event! 1
140486871191712
4 150
<__main__.LP_LP_c_ushort object at 0x7fc5a60d9200>
<__main__.LP_eventNode object at 0x7fc5a60d9170>
<__main__.LP_eventNode object at 0x7fc5a60d9290>
```

But the problem is, that even though I know there should be many events in the list, it only iterates once and then stops. The problem seems to be with those last few lines, that even though `cur` gets assigned to `cur.contents.next`, the address seems to change 0x...170 becomes 0x...290 after the assignment. Attempting to dereference `cur` after this point raises a NULL poitner exception. I think I'm missing something about pointers and assignment in Python, but I'm not sure what to do.

PS the access to `cur.contents.channels` and `cur.contents.samples` returns exactly what I expect it to for the one object that I am able to access, indicating that it is working at least partially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `next` and `prev` flipped around in the ctypes definition of `eventNode`. So when you use `next` you're actually getting the `NULL` value of `prev`.

The changing `LP_eventNode` addresses are unrelated. That's the address of the Python object created each time you access the `Structure` field.

```
from ctypes import *

class eventNode(Structure):
    pass

eventNode._fields_ = [
    ("channels", c_int),
    ("samples", c_int),
    ("event", POINTER(POINTER(c_uint16))),
    ("next", POINTER(eventNode)),
    ("prev", POINTER(eventNode)),
]
```

---

`_fields_` is defined as a `tuple` or `list` such that the order is preserved for calculating the offset of each field. The `CField` descriptors in the type specify the ctypes type, the size, and the offset of each field.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea that order was important when defining `_fields_`. If that was in the documentation I must have missed it somehow. And I actually did define the `argtypes` I just left it out for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Now that I see it it makes sense why that should be, the original declaration of the 'struct' is invisible to Python. Thanks again.